# Is measurability of Stochastic Transition Kernels preserved by intersections

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

I have a technical question regarding the measurability
of functions of the form
$R(A,y)$ where $R(\cdot,y)$ is a measure.

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ and $(Y,\mathfrak{A})$ be measurable spaces.
Suppose we have a (regular) stochastic transition kernel
$$ R: \Sigma \times Y \to \mathbb R \,.$$
Say stemming from a (regular) conditional probability w.r.t. a measurable mapping $\pi: (X,\Sigma) \to (Y,\mathfrak{A})$.

We can extend the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ to the completion w.r.t. $R(\cdot,y)$.
Lets call this completion $\Sigma_y$.

Let $\nu$ be a probability measure on $(Y,\mathfrak A)$.
Now suppose that $A,B \subseteq X$ are $\nu$-almost surely
measurable w.r.t. $\Sigma_y$.

**Now I can pose my question:**

It can be that $y\mapsto R(A,y)$ as well as $y \mapsto R(B,y)$
are almost surely equal to $\Sigma$-measurable maps.
(This is true by definition of a transition kernel for $A,B \in \Sigma$
but it can be true for many more sets.)
Is it then also the case that $y\mapsto R(A\cap B, y)$
is also almost surely measurable?
Does the same hold if we replace $\Sigma$ by some other $\sigma$-algebra?